# The dual Lie algebra in the context of Hamiltonian action

Tags: linear-algebra, group-actions, symplectic-geometry

Let $t$ be  a  Lie  algebra.  what is  the  precise  structure of  the  dual  lie  algebra $t^*$  when  we  are  considering the momentum  map  associated to  a  Lie  group  action on a  symplectic  manifold in the  context of  Hamiltonian action?

Comment: Do you mean the definition, or something more?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier  Yes  I  mean the  definition.

Comment: I also had the same query as I was studying these things. For anyone in the future who may wind up here, the answer is (as I understand it): $t^*$ is just the vector space dual. With $t$ being finite dimensional, it is canonically isomorphic to its dual, and this can be used to define the Lie bracket on $t^*$.